# ViewPager: onPageSelected not being call if user swipe below or equal 50% of a screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a Viewpager that show a list calendar of month and when I try to swipe each tab sometime it's hard to go to another tab like when user have to scroll to another page there is 2 possibility:

- User have to swipe fast so it will work fine
- If user scroll slowly, they have to move the page larger than 50% of the screen to move next or right

So in the second case it make my user hard to swipe between each tab because it take a bit longer just to move between each tab

> In recycler view user don't need to swipe larger than 50% of the screen to move the page though

Comment: yes that is the use case of onPage selected once page is selected then only callback is triggered. when do you want a callback?

Comment: @Anmol I want it to have the same behavior like recycler view

Comment: then Use ViewPager2 anyway they have removed maintenance support for ViewPager and ViewPager2 has better and simpler api's

Comment: actually I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter so its default extend the viewpager